# Ruby On Rails runs some database queries after the server starts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have a Rails app that runs a lot of likely unnecessary data queries when the server starts.

I would like to know how to prevent that. Is there a way to detect what makes the queries run?

My app uses active admin. Thanks in advance.

```
$ rails server
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  Event Load (112.3ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  EXPLAIN (97.8ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
EXPLAIN for: SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys              | key                        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | events | ref  | index_events_on_is_enabled | index_events_on_is_enabled | 2       | const |    2 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)

  Team Load (99.6ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.9ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.0ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (101.0ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Language Load (98.1ms)  SELECT `languages`.* FROM `languages` 
  Event Load (105.8ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  Team Load (98.5ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.8ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.7ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.5ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Event Load (105.8ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  Team Load (98.3ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (100.1ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.9ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.6ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
  Event Load (199.4ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1
  Team Load (100.2ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.6ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (100.6ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.5ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Event Load (104.8ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  Team Load (98.9ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (99.0ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.9ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (100.4ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Event Load (104.8ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  Team Load (99.6ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.2ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.5ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (98.1ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Language Load (97.9ms)  SELECT `languages`.* FROM `languages` 
  Event Load (106.1ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  Team Load (98.9ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (97.6ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (102.5ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (126.3ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Event Load (104.9ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  Team Load (98.3ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (100.4ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (100.5ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (100.1ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Event Load (104.7ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  Team Load (99.0ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (97.9ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (100.1ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (99.1ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Event Load (104.7ms)  SELECT `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE `events`.`is_enabled` = 1 ORDER BY start_date_time
  Team Load (98.9ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 365 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (99.1ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 382 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (99.7ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 2503 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  Team Load (99.1ms)  SELECT `teams`.* FROM `teams` WHERE `teams`.`espn_id` = 160 ORDER BY abbreviation ASC LIMIT 1
  LeaderBoardRange Load (98.8ms)  SELECT `leader_board_ranges`.* FROM `leader_board_ranges` WHERE `leader_board_ranges`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  LeaderBoardRange Load (99.1ms)  SELECT `leader_board_ranges`.* FROM `leader_board_ranges` WHERE `leader_board_ranges`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  EventPollRelationship Load (103.9ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `event_poll_relationships`.* FROM `event_poll_relationships` INNER JOIN `votes` ON `votes`.`event_poll_relationship_id` = `event_poll_relationships`.`id` WHERE (votes.created_at > '2014-01-24 13:38:50')
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: can you add some examples of the queries?

Comment: You're going to have to give more information, or no one is going to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by active admin and some custom index scopes that are dynamic. To fix it you can disable or tweak these custom scopes.

Eg:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.16 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Thin web server (v1.6.1 codename Death Proof)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```